# How to add data into json-server database

Tags: javascript, post, fetch, json-server

This is my json-server database.

```
{
  "users": {
    "sarahedo": {
      "id": "sarahedo",
      "name": "Sarah Edo",
      "avatarURL": "https://pluralsight.imgix.net/author/lg/6f77d113-ea36-4592-814d-9d4acb32f231.jpg",
      "answers": {
        "8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd": "optionOne",
        "6ni6ok3ym7mf1p33lnez": "optionOne",
        "am8ehyc8byjqgar0jgpub9": "optionTwo",
        "loxhs1bqm25b708cmbf3g": "optionTwo"
      },
      "questions": ["8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd", "am8ehyc8byjqgar0jgpub9"]
    },
}
```

I need to add new ID in "questions": ["8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd", "am8ehyc8byjqgar0jgpub9"]
but I can't access it in fetch URL.

I tried to check the URL in browser "HTTP://localhost:3000/users/sarahedo"
I get empty object for some reason {}

I want to know how can I add new data to it using fetch POST.

Comment: Share your js code, without it is difficult to understand what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you get an empty object from `http://localhost:3000/users/sarahedo` is that you've defined your data in `.json` file incorrectly. If you correct your `.json` file with the below data, you'll see your user obj by hitting `http://localhost:3000/users/sarahedo` in the browser.

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": "sarahedo",
      "name": "Sarah Edo",
      "avatarURL": "https://pluralsight.imgix.net/author/lg/6f77d113-ea36-4592-814d-9d4acb32f231.jpg",
      "answers": {
        "8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd": "optionOne",
        "6ni6ok3ym7mf1p33lnez": "optionOne",
        "am8ehyc8byjqgar0jgpub9": "optionTwo",
        "loxhs1bqm25b708cmbf3g": "optionTwo"
      },
      "questions": [
        "8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd",
        "am8ehyc8byjqgar0jgpub9"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You can either use below code for adding new data, using fetch POST:

```
async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    return response.json()
  }
```

For more detailed info about fetch POST, check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options